# How to read author-information from an office file?

Tags: api, .net-2.0, ms-office

I have a bunch of office 2003 documents (.ppt, .doc, .xls) in a folder, and need to extract the "author" property from each file. What would be the best way to do this, is there some sort of (free) office-api I could use to read this information?

I'm using .NET 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [an article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224351) on MSDN about Dsofile.dll which seems to work as expected. Other suggestions are still welcome.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/757466-c-app-reading-modifying-ms-office-document-meta-data#post3027298) contains some code for accessing MS Office file properties.

A [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/SummInfoPropSetFile.aspx) - it's in c++, but it might be useful.

[This](http://www.xtractpro.com/articles/Office-Properties.aspx) looks like the most promising article.